# slim3 distributed transaction on appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, bigtable

from example

```
@Model
public class Account {

    @Attribute(primaryKey = true)
    private Key key;

    private Integer balance;
    ...
}
```

from example http://sites.google.com/site/slim3appengine/ 
i do not understand why doing money transfer need 2 different transaction as this is only one entity (same entity)

```
  Acount src = gtx.get(Acount.class, srcKey);    //arent src and des same entity? why do 2 trans?
    Acount dest = gtx.get(Acount.class, destKey);
    if (src.getBalance() >= amount) {
        src.setBalance(src.getBalance() - amount);
        dest.setBalance(dest.getBalance() + amount);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

src and dest are different entities - you're fetching them with separate keys (srcKey and destKey).

Comment: is separate entity, i agreed. but both using same entity group. so cant transaction done in one cycle? rather than 2?

Comment: @cometta They're not in the same entity group. Entity groups are entities with the same parent, and both of the entities above are root entities, with no parents.